# Почему build:gradle:1.5.0 показывает ошибку?

Tags: android

Я имплементировал библиотеку в свой проект и столкнулся с такой ситуацией, для того, чтоб она работала и не вылетало никаких ошибок нужно было поменять версию `android.tools` на пониженную. У меня по дефолту была вот такая

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

и пока я ее не поменял на вот такую (пониженную)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

у меня вываливалась вот такая ошибка

```
Error:Cannot access first() element from an empty List
```

если версия старая 1.2.3 то все работает, а когда ставлю 1.5.0 , то не работает...

Почему так получается? Что делать если я хочу использовать новые версии?

Answer (score 1):

Решение из разряда очевидного, вам необходимо юзать более новую версию, а не старую.
"чтоб она работала и не вылетало никаких ошибок нужно было поменять версию android.tools на пониженную." Сильно сомневаюсь, что это правильное решение проблемы

Comment: Так нет как раз наоборот... Согласно моего вопроса там написано, что если версия старая 1.2.3 то все работает, а когда ставлю 1.5.0 , то не работает...

Comment: "Я имплементировал библиотеку в свой проект и столкнулся с такой ситуацией, для того, чтоб она работала и не вылетало никаких ошибок нужно было поменять версию android.tools на пониженную." Вы где-то об этом прочитали или методом тыка определили, что на пониженной версии всё нормально. Вот сами подумайте, на старой версии работает, а на новой нет, возможно проблема в другом, т.к. обычно новые версии чего-либо содержат старое и что-то новое и поэтому "что-то" старое должно тоже работать

Comment: Я тоже так думал... Но на практике получается по другому. Я определил это методом тыка... Я новичок поэтому могу, что то не так понять... Но вот сами смотрите какая ситуация, ставлю версию 1.5.0 показывает ошибку, ставлю версию 1.2.3 все работает... В чем причина?